# Drupal 7 Aggregate and compress CSS/JS not working with Amazon S3

Tags: drupal-7

I am using Amazon S3 and enable the Bandwidth optimization form Drupal 7 performance page:

- Aggregate and compress CSS files
- Aggregate JavaScript files

and Enable the S3fs setting as follow:

[image: Add S3 option for public and private folder]

but after enable the Bandwidth optimization form Drupal 7 performance page. it not working properly(not updated the changes in css files.). please note I have clear the cache as well several time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed and found that we need to clear the Aggregate and compress CSS files using Aggregate action pages. when I have deleted the all store css and js cache and cache files using Aggregate action pages. all think is working fine.